# How to give action to a single floating button of three normal buttons in tabs in android

Tags: android, button, tabs, action, floating-action-button

Can anyone help me that how to give action to floating button of various buttons.  I have 3 buttons in my tabbed activity in different tabs. And i wanna give that 3 buttons actions to single floating button

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution will be creating three listeners or just a single listener call back which will be registered 3 seperate button and when user clicks on any of the button callback will go to `FloatingActionButton`'s operation.

Comment: Can you please give me any example